# X axis rescaling without altering the y axis

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have asked this question previously and I didn’t get a satisfactory answer. Then I posted a comment and didn’t receive any replies. So I thought to elaborate my issue.
I have:

> Plot[{Sin[t]^2}, {t, 0, 3000}, Background -> White]

Then I get
[image: cc]

> Plot[{Sin[t]^2}, {t, 0, 3000}, Background -> White,   Ticks -> {{#,
> 1/902*Pi/4 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0., 3000}, 6] //
> N, Automatic}]

Then I get:
[image: bhj]

When you compare two figures,  I rescaled the x axis in second figure without altering y axis with new ticks. But actually when you look you can see that second plot  can be  written in terms of Pi multiples. But I don’t know how. Any way?

Comment: Just remove `// N`?

Comment: @kglr That’s great. But it not as standard notation as 0,Pi/4,Pi/2,3pi/4 , Pi!

Comment: does `Ticks -> {Transpose[{Rescale[#, {0, Pi}, {0, 3000}], #} &@
    FindDivisions[{0, Pi, Pi/16}, 8, Method -> {}]], Automatic}` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr It’s working. But I am not sure where did you incorporate 1/902*Pi/4.

Comment: if you want the horizontal range to go from 0 to 3000 Pi /902/4 (as x goes from 0 to 3000) try `Ticks -> {Transpose[{Rescale[#, {0, 3000 Pi/902/4}, {0, 3000}], #} &@
    FindDivisions[{0, 3000 Pi/902/4, Pi/16}, 8, Method -> {}]],   Automatic}`

Comment: @kglr It’s working great

Comment: If you use `Plot[{Sin[t]^2}, {t, 0, 3000}, MaxRecursion -> 15]` you will see that a more precise plot displays as a solid block with no structure. Why use an example which has no meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xticks = Transpose[{4 # 902 / Pi, #}] &@
  FindDivisions[{0, 3000 Pi/902/4, Pi/16}, 8, Method -> {}]

Plot[Sin[t]^2, {t, 0, 3000}, Ticks -> {xtikcs, Automatic}]
```

[image]